# Iterating through XML file via c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have this type of XML file storing configuration values:

```
<assets>
  <asset enabled="false" name="ListTypes" internalName="List" duplicateCheckField="" enableCustomFields="true"></asset>
  <asset enabled="false" name="Members" internalName="Member" duplicateCheckField="Username" enableCustomFields="false"></asset>
</assets>
```

I would like to iterate through each asset and get each elements value, and store it in a list of assets.

I have the following code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            processConfiguration();
        }

        public static void processConfiguration()
        {
            XDocument assets = XDocument.Load("assets.xml");
            List<asset> assetList = new List<asset>();

            // this line is not working out for me as I cannot get each attr value
            // by attr I mean enabled, name, etc for each row
            foreach (var row in assets.Descendants("asset").ToList())
            {
                asset a = new asset();
                // once i have the foreach correct I can build my list.
            }

        }

        public class asset
        {
            public bool enabled { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string internalName { get; set; }
            public string duplicateCheckField { get; set; }
            public bool enableCustomFields { get; set; }

        }

    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't use `ToList` in a `foreach` - there is no purpose. You can access the attributes using the `XElement.Attribute()` method: `row.Attribute("name").Value`.

Comment: Also note that `XAttribute` implements explicit casting so you can do stuff like `a.enabled = (bool)row.Attribute("enabled");`

Comment: @NetMage Add that as the answer so you get credit for saving some time for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XElement.Attribute` to access the attribute values. You can also use LINQ to XML to shorten the code:

```
XDocument assets = XDocument.Load("assets.xml");
var assetList = assets.Descendants("asset")
                      .Select(row => new asset {
                           enabled = (bool)row.Attribute("enabled"),
                           name = row.Attribute("name").Value,
                           internalName = row.Attribute("internalName").Value,
                           duplicateCheckField = row.Attribute("duplicateCheckField").Value,
                           enableCustomFields = (bool)row.Attribute("enabledCustomFields")
                       }).ToList();
```